# Question about Slutsky's Theorem: How to Show Convergence for $Y_n$ if Knowing a $E(X_n-Y_n)^2 \longrightarrow 0$ Term between Two Distributions

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X_n \longrightarrow \theta$ in probability, where $\theta$ is a constant and $E(X_n - Y_n)^2  \longrightarrow 0$ in probability, can we say $Y_n  \longrightarrow \theta$ in probability?

My first thought is to write the MSE term into$$
E(X_n - Y_n)^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_n [(X_n)^2 - 2(X_n)(Y_n) + (Y_n)^2],
$$ and then figure out each term in the expansion.

1. $\frac{1}{n}\sum_n (X_n)^2$: Since $X_n \longrightarrow \theta$ in probability, $g(X_n) \longrightarrow g(\theta)$ in probability. Thus, $g(X_n) \longrightarrow g(\theta)=\theta^2$. Plug into the above form, we can have $\frac{1}{n} * n * \theta^2 = \theta^2$.
2. $\frac{1}{n} \sum_n 2(X_n)(Y_n)$: Assuming $Y_n \longrightarrow y$ in probability, then by the Slutsky's theorem, it can be expressed as $\frac{1}{n}*n*y\theta = y\theta$.
3. $\frac{1}{n} \sum_n (Y_n)^2$: Following the similar calculation above, we can have $\frac{1}{n} * n * y^2 = y^2$.

Since $E(X_n - Y_n)^2  \longrightarrow 0$ in probability, thus $y$ must be equal to $\theta$.

However, I am not quite sure the above calculation is correct or not, since if we take limit for deterministic sequence such as $\frac{1}{n}$, it goes to 0 as n goes to infinity, which causes the above calculation doesn't work anymore I think.

Comment: an expectation, if it exists, is (plus or minus) infinity or a real number, so it cannot converge in probability (it is not a random variable), maybe you mean pointwise convergence of $E(X_n-Y_n)^2$ to zero?

Comment: Yes, I mean it is pointwise convergence to zero.

Comment: what is this $E(X_n - Y_n)^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i [(X_n)_i^2 - 2(X_n)_i(Y_n)_i + (Y_n)_i^2]$? The LHS is infinity or a non-negative real number, but the RHS seems a function, what mean $(X_n)_i$ ?

Comment: Actually, I am not quite sure whether my expansion in RHS is correct. Or it should be expanded as $\sum_n X_n^2 -2X_nY_n + Y_n^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\{|Y_n-X_n|+|X_n-\theta|>\varepsilon\}\subset\{|Y_n-X_n|>\varepsilon/2\}\cup\{|X_n-\theta|>\varepsilon/2\},$$
\begin{align*}
P(|Y_n-\theta|>\varepsilon)
&=P(|Y_n-X_n+X_n-\theta|>\varepsilon)\\
&\le P(|Y_n-X_n|+|X_n-\theta|>\varepsilon)\\
&\le P(|Y_n-X_n|>\varepsilon/2)+P(|X_n-\theta|>\varepsilon/2)
\end{align*}
using the triangle inequality. Using Markov's inequality,
$$
P(|Y_n-X_n|>\varepsilon/2)\le\frac{\operatorname E|Y_n-X_n|^2}{(\varepsilon/2)^2}
$$
and since $\operatorname E|Y_n-X_n|^2\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, we conclude that $Y_n\to\theta$ in probability as $n\to\infty$.

I hope this helps.